# How can I feed multiple of 100 annotated files in training Custom NER model using spacy3

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, entities, spacy-3

Currently I have prepared a Custom NER model where I can extract 15 entities. I have trained my model on single annotated file using config.cfg file by spacy3. Now I want to train my model again on 100 annotated files. How can I pass these annotated files?

Answer (score 0):

If you put `.spacy` files in a directory and specify the directory as your train/dev corpus spaCy will automatically load all the files.

Comment: I am working with spacy3 and my task is to create a model which can extract 26 entities from a pdf. So I have 200 documents where I have to work with custom NER. I am confused how to pass the multiple data files and create single .spacy format file  for training because I am training my model through spacy CLI command where I can give only one training and testing file.

Comment: Please read the docs. https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data